# Delete key from configmap in Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, configmap

Is there a nice way to delete a specific key from a Kubernetes configmap, using kubectl?

Right now I run:

```
$ kubectl edit configmap myconfigmap
```

and then I delete the entry but I would like a solution that can be run as a script.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

This works but I wonder if there is a simpler way

```
$ kubectl patch configmap myconfigmap --type=json -p='[{"op": "remove", "path": "/data/mykey"}]'
```

Comment: There are no `kubectl` commands to edit configmaps as of now, so `patch` is the way to go - and how simpler than a single command do you want to go? :)